# Lightroom alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editor

What is the best alternative to Adobe Lightroom on Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been quite happy with using [Bibble 5](http://bibblelabs.com/).

While it is a commercial program, I find it outstrips all open-source solutions in both usability and speed - at least for my uses. And they have quite good Linux support, including .deb-packages and simultaneous releases on all platforms.

Comment: Yes, Bibble is great. This was my final choice.

Answer (score 11):

I quite like F-Spot + UFRAW for organising photos and processing them but I also use [Darktable](http://darktable.sourceforge.net/) for when I get bored of UFRAW.

Answer (score 7):

I use Darktable too. If your camera is supported [RawTherapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/) will be an option as well.

Answer (score 4):

the best I like is digiKam but there are also UFRAW, RawTherapee and Shotwell(RAW support in development).

There are also Lightzone and Bibble if you are looking for commercial products.

Answer (score 4):

Darktable all the way.  Extremely versatile and well-thought-out RAW workflow tool.  It's a new-ish project, but you'd never know it from the features and stability.  There's an official release, as well as PPAs available for those of us who like the latest and greatest (and don't mind the odd hiccup, though those have been rare for me).

Be sure to watch the tutorial videos on their Sourceforge page... many features and functions are not immediately obvious to first-time users.

I've also used RawTherapee to great effect, but at the moment, Darktable beats it hands-down.

-Mark

Answer (score 3):

I'm shooting sports 3-5 times per week(400-1000 shots per event) and I use Darktable for my needs.

Also I download and organize my photos with Rapid Photo Downloader.